# Access Library corruption?

Tags: ms-access

I am troubleshooting an Access Database that stored in a shared folder. The database will grab the data from 2 excel spreadsheets and use "Union" query to merge the data and then generate a report.

The problem I am running into is: I ran the database on Computer A, B and C. From computer A and C, the report is good; but when I ran it on computer B, certain part of the report is missing.

I re-install Office 365 on computer B, and that didn't help. I am thinking the Access library was corrupted, or a bad hardware driver

Is there log or an event viewer for Access 2013 that I can monitor every singe step? Appreciate for any ideas/suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when Access report controls go slightly off a page, it hides the entire control. Check the default printer on the problem computer. Try setting it to the same as the others.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that you're mapping to the shared folder in a valid way on each computer?

For example, if the shared folder is mapped to drive letter F:\ on one computer and G:\ on another computer, there won't be any hardcoded file that you'll be able to use to access the file.